# pandas group by and fill in the missing time interval sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,21,21,21,31,31,31,31,31],
                   'time' :[-1,5,17,11,25,39,46,4,100,150,1],
                   'value':[101,102,121,120,143,153,160,170,96,97,99]})
```

What I would like to do is

a) FIll in the missing `time` by generating a sequence number (ex:1,2,3,4) and copy the value (for all other columns) from the previous row

I was trying something like below

```
df.groupby(['person_id']).cumcount() + 1
df['sequence'] = g.cumcount() + 1
```

But this doesn't help me get the expected output

I expect my output to be like as shown below (SAMPLE OF 1 SUBJECT IS SHOWN BELOW)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's set the `time` column as the index of dataframe then `groupby` the dataframe on `person_id` then for each group classified by `person_id` [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the group to conform its `index` with the range of values specified in `time` column, finally [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all the groups to get the desired dataframe:

```
grp = df.set_index('time').groupby('person_id')
groups = [g.reindex(range(g.index.min(), g.index.max() + 1)).ffill().reset_index() for _, g in grp]
out = pd.concat(groups, ignore_index=True).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Alternatively you can first create tuple pairs for each `person_id` and corresponding range of values specified in `time` column  then  `reindex` the dataframe:

```
grp = df.groupby('person_id')['time']
idx = [(k, n) for k, t in grp  for n in range(t.min(), t.max() + 1)]
out = df.set_index(['person_id', 'time']).reindex(idx).ffill().reset_index()
```

Result (for person_id `11`):

```
    person_id  time  value
0        11.0    -1  101.0
1        11.0     0  101.0
2        11.0     1  101.0
3        11.0     2  101.0
4        11.0     3  101.0
5        11.0     4  101.0
6        11.0     5  102.0
7        11.0     6  102.0
8        11.0     7  102.0
9        11.0     8  102.0
10       11.0     9  102.0
11       11.0    10  102.0
12       11.0    11  102.0
13       11.0    12  102.0
14       11.0    13  102.0
15       11.0    14  102.0
16       11.0    15  102.0
17       11.0    16  102.0
18       11.0    17  121.0
```

Comment: Unfortnately I get this error `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: @TheGreat As the `dtype` of `time` column is `float64` first we need ti change the `dtype` to `int` as the `range` accepts its argumets as integers..alternatively you can use `np.r_[g.index.min(): g.index.max() + 1]` in place of `range` if you don't want to change the `dtype`.

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`
not sure why I get this error
it it because of duplicate data point?

Comment: Its totally possible because some of my time values could repeat..

Answer (score 2):

the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can help with missing rows; it can handle duplicates as well :

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build a dictionary
# pairing time with range of min and max time
time = {'time' : lambda df: range(df.min(), df.max()+1)}

# complete the rows
# the expansion is done per `person_id`
outcome = (df.complete(time, by='person_id', sort = True)
             .ffill(downcast='infer'))
 
outcome
     person_id  time  value
0           11    -1    101
1           11     0    101
2           11     1    101
3           11     2    101
4           11     3    101
..         ...   ...    ...
193         31   146     96
194         31   147     96
195         31   148     96
196         31   149     96
197         31   150     97


outcome.query('person_id == 11')
    person_id  time  value
0          11    -1    101
1          11     0    101
2          11     1    101
3          11     2    101
4          11     3    101
5          11     4    101
6          11     5    102
7          11     6    102
8          11     7    102
9          11     8    102
10         11     9    102
11         11    10    102
12         11    11    102
13         11    12    102
14         11    13    102
15         11    14    102
16         11    15    102
17         11    16    102
18         11    17    121
```

Comment: appreciate the effort. thanks, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

The key is to 'reindex' per group min/max and fill forward. See one of the approaches below,

```
(df.groupby('person_id')['time']
   .apply(lambda x:np.arange(x.min(), x.max()))
   .explode()
   .reset_index()
   .merge(df, how='left')
   .ffill()
)
```